# D3DImage loses device on WPF application

Tags: c#, directx

I am developing a WPF application that displays a directX scene. 
The code that generates the directX scene is not mine and I have no access to it. (Its not a public code I can references you guys to)

Everything was working fine until I had to format my PC and installed Windows 10. (Before that I had Windows 7)
Now I can't see the DirectX scene and the RenderCapability.Tier on WPF returns 0.

The code works on other computers (Windows 7 and Windows 10) so I'm guessing its something to do with my computer but nothing changed hardware-wise..
I tried reinstalling DirectX and I tried reinstalling the display driver (tried several different drivers) but nothing works I still get RenderCapability.Tier = 0.

The code that displays the DirectX scene is mostly taken from this link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage

I couldn't find any help around the internet that actually solved my problem.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you installed slimdx? Or did you used sharpdx

Comment: Neither. Why would I need them? I am not very experienced with DirectX so I could be wrong here.. As I said I am using a different set of DLLs that actually create the scene and I a just using a D3DImage to display it in my WPF app. It worked alright 'til now..

Answer (score 0):

Run dxdiag.exe, Display tab, ensure it prints "D3D acceleration: enabled" and "No problems found".

Also the linked sample has a bug, on some systems you must use a query to wait for completion of rendering before passing the texture to WPF. Otherwise WPF may show incomplete renderings, or none at all. If you render with DX9, [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/queries), you need D3DQUERYTYPE_EVENT query, issue D3DISSUE_END after you've done rendering, then sleep until GetData returns S_OK.

Comment: dxdiag does say that D3D Acceleration is enabled. The same exact code works on other computers so I really think its a configuration issue with my computer.. Something weird though with dxdiag is that I have an extra display tab (Im using 3 monitors and I have 4 Display tabs) and the extra one shows errors.